# HTML return an array in $_POST

Tags: html, arrays, forms, addition

I have an HTML form (for an hotel) where I need to add one or more rooms. The code I wrote is:

```
<html>
    <header>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var i = 1;
              $("#add").click(function() {
                  div = document.createElement('div');
                  $(div).addClass("room").html('Room Type: <input type="text" name="RoomType[' + i + ']" value="Triple">' 
                                                +  ' Beds: <input type="text" name="RoomBeds[' + i + ']" value="3">'
                                                +  ' Qty: <input type="text" name="RoomQty[' + i + ']" value="28"><br>');
                  $("#roomTypes").append(div);
                  i = i+1;
                });
            });
            
        </script>
        <style>
            #container {border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px; width: 100%;}
            .inner {border: 1px solid green; margin: 10px; width: auto; height: 20px;}
           </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <form action="printForm.php" method="post">
            <div id="roomTypes">
                <div class="room">
                    Room Type: <input type="text" name="RoomType[0]" value="Double">
                    Beds: <input type="text" name="RoomBeds[0]" value="2">
                    Qty: <input type="text" name="RoomQty[0]" value="29"><br>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="add">Add Room Type</button>
            
            <br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

I receive and display this form with this PHP code:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

?>
```

Obtaining the following result (an array of columns, instead of rows..):

```
Array ( [RoomType] => Array ( [0] => Double ) [RoomBeds] => Array ( [0] => 2 ) [RoomQty] => Array ( [0] => 29 ) )
```

Is there an elegant way to receive an array like this (an array of rows)?

```
Array ( [Room] => Array ( [0] => Double [Beds] => 2 [Qty] =>29 ) ...)
```

Comment: Thanks. But my question was regarding sending a correctly formed array at form (POST) level..

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.
I've changed my HTML form code this way:

```
<html>
    <header>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var i = 1;
              $("#add").click(function() {
                  div = document.createElement('div');
                  $(div).addClass("room").html('Room Type: <input type="text" name="Room[' + i + '][0]" value="Triple">' 
                                                +  ' Beds: <input type="text" name="Room[' + i + '][1]" value="3">'
                                                +  ' Qty: <input type="text" name="Room[' + i + '][2]" value="28"><br>');
                  $("#roomTypes").append(div);
                  i = i+1;
                });
            });
            
        </script>
        <style>
            #container {border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px; width: 100%;}
            .inner {border: 1px solid green; margin: 10px; width: auto; height: 20px;}
           </style>
    </header>
    <body>
        <form action="printForm.php" method="post">
            <div id="roomTypes">
                <div class="room">
                    Room Type: <input type="text" name="Room[0][0]" value="Double">
                    Beds: <input type="text" name="Room[0][1]" value="2">
                    Qty: <input type="text" name="Room[0][2]" value="29"><br>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <button type="button" id="add">Add Room Type</button>
            
            <br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

So, now I can receive a well formed array.